# File retrieval and extraction from Amazon Glacier

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-glacier

I backup my Synology Diskstation files to an Amazon Glacier account and have used FastGlacier to download a file from there, but I'm not sure how to view/extract this file (it has no file type).

While browsing my account, all the file names are hashed and it is unclear which file is which, so I assumed these were my files that have been compressed. Can anyone offer some advice as to how to view the file I've downloaded?

Comment: How did you upload the file.  Amazon wouldn't compress the files unless you indicate you wanted to do that.  With compression comes the chance even if its remote that corruption can happen hence the reason we have lossless compression.  Amazon wouldn't compress your file, *they don't care*, you actually *pay them more* if you upload a larger file.

Comment: That's a good point, I might have mistaken the files to be compressed when actually they could be encrypted? In any case, my problem still remains! My NAS (synology diskstation) has an Amazon Glacier integration which I use to upload my files.

Comment: I can't tell you if the files are encrypted.  You have to determine that.  Might help if you determine that then update your question.

Answer (score 0):

There is a script on github to unpack the files from glacier backup without the need for a diskstation:

https://github.com/ryanschulze/synology-glacier-restore

If you did not choose encryption during backup, data is most likely not encrypted.